# How to extract multiple JSON objects from one json file located outside the app directory in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, object, parsing

I am very new to Json files. If I have a json file with multiple json objects, located outside the app asset directory in angular at /var/log, the json objects are like such as following:

```
{"ID":"12345","Timestamp":"20140101", "Usefulness":"Yes",
 "Code":[{"event1":"A","result":"1"},…]}
{"ID":"1A35B","Timestamp":"20140102", "Usefulness":"No",
 "Code":[{"event1":"B","result":"1"},…]}
{"ID":"AA356","Timestamp":"20140103", "Usefulness":"No",
 "Code":[{"event1":"B","result":"0"},…]}
```

I want to extract all "Timestamp" and "Usefulness" into a data frames in angular js, this is my code:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
//import json from '../../../../../../../../var/log/suricata/eve.json';
import data from "../../../../../../../../var/log/suricata/eve.json";
import { ClassToggleService, HeaderComponent } from '@coreui/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-default-header',
  templateUrl: './default-header.component.html',
})
export class DefaultHeaderComponent extends HeaderComponent {

  @Input() sidebarId: string = "sidebar";

  public newMessages = new Array(4)
  public newTasks = new Array(5)
  public newNotifications = new Array(5)


  constructor(private classToggler: ClassToggleService) {
    super();
    
    let products: any = (data as any).default;
    const myJSON = JSON.stringify(products);
    var res = JSON.parse('[' + products.replace(/}}}{/g, '}}},{') + ']');
    console.log(res);
    //console.log(data.timestamp);
    //console.log(data.stats.uptime);
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know you're not allowed to access the users' filesystem this way. You have to setup local storage and make sure the logs go there so you can access them.

Comment: Ok but how can I read multiple objects as they are not in form of array?

Comment: As it's not JSON compliant you would have to write your own parsing function for this. I would look for a regular expression to solve this for you. Extract an JSON object, convert that to a Javascript object and then do the next.

Comment: Any possible solution?